# Android Studio doesn't see ArrayList class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

Android Studio 0.5.1 doesn't see ArrayList class. Quick Definition suggest me create a new one. 
Even when I try to import `java.util.ArrayList;`

It works only if I set `import java.util.*;`, but Quick Definition still doesn't see.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try upgrading your Android Studio. 0.5.1 is really old and AFAIK, earlier versions were filled with bugs. Newer versions are a lot better, but still some bugs.

Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with your code regarding ArrayList.

Comment: This question is over 2 years old, by the way

Comment: Wow, didn't notice. I don't know why, but it came up in my feed of recent questions. Thanks.

Comment: Question was editted recently. Edits get bumped to the front page

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same. But I use a current version (3.1.4). I have to add the import statement manually and don't get autocorrections/hints.

Comment: Well obviously Android Studio creators damned ArrayList :D ... version 3.5.3 and still must manually import...